# Javascript style change for 2nd level child node

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a case like in this picture

[image]

where I know the unique id of element 1, element 2 id isn't unique so needs to be accessed as a child, and the div inside element 2 doesn't have any unique identifier so also has to be accessed as a child node

So far I tried something like this

```
`document.querySelector(`tr.${current_id} > td.color > div`).setAttribute('style', 'background-color: rgb(0,0,255);');`
```

but get "cannot read set Attribute of null" so it's not working. Any idea how I could perform this in pure JS and the simplest way?

Jquery is also a option but ideally want to do this just with JS.

Comment: change `tr.${current_id} > td.color > div` to `tr#${current_id} > td#color > div` . Assuming you know it is not valid HTML because IDs should be unique. So a better fix is, leave as is and change `id="color"` to `class="color"`

Comment: Having `#id` assigned to two or more different elements is very invalid. If you insist on using duplicate values then use `class`.

Comment: the code base isn't mine, I'm adding a feature to a already existing interface, and yes having multiple same id's is ofcourse invalid but its not in my power to make changes there

Comment: @caramba using your suggestion I'm getting "not a valid selector"

Comment: I've worked under simular circumstances where I had no control over the clunky outdated (but not invalid) HTML/CSS from the back-end. However, once it was on the front end (ie a loaded webpage), I would alter it however I pleased. It would benefit you greatly if you replaced `id` with `class` . If you did that, something so simple as referencing a `<div>` wouldn't be such a problem as it is now.

Comment: Also, any solution to your problem is most likely limited in usefulness. I'm assuming that the rest of the HTML involves more `<tr>` with `<td>` assigned with duplicated `id`. Have you considered how you'd differentiate between `<tr>`s? How about `<td>`?

Comment: it definitely is clunky, but it is still alright so far since each row is grouped in a <tr> with unique row id. I have been able to retrieve data from these rows quite easily even though it took me more setup time. I'm just not too experienced in DOM yet, to make that style change with the current grouping system. But I'm sure my attempt was pretty close and it can be done even with this poor id nomenclature

Comment: the <tr> and <td> madness is used to create a "table" of sorts to a 3rd party 3d viewer provider as a user interface, I will update the question with more details

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why but by doing this I found the `querySelector` stops complaining and also finds the correct child node div. If anyone is experiencing a similar problem by defining the parent node the `querySelector` worked as inteded

```
let group = document.getElementById(current_id);
group.querySelector(`td#color > div`).setAttribute('style', 'background-color: rgb(0,0,255);');
```

In refernece to the picture from the question, `group` variable is element labeled 1.

PS. thanks to @caramba for correcting my element referencing format